# How to verify json response in controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails controller that returns only json

```
def index
  if params[:filtered] = 'someValue'
    @json = Model.where(some_conditions).to_json 
  else
    @json = Model.where(some_other_conditions).to_json 
  end
  render json: @json
end
```

What is the correct way to test that the action is returning the expected @json objects?

I've tried the following

```
describe "GET #index" do  
  before :each do
    get :index, filtered: 'someValue'
  end
  it { expect( response.body ).to eq 'my expected response' }
end
```

But I'm getting

```
Failure/Error: it { expect( response.body ).to eq 'my expected response' }
expected: 'my expected response'
got: "[]"
```

I'm having trouble determining whether there is a problem in the underlying controller, or whether I've simply written a bad test.

Is `response.body` the correct way to get the json payload?

Help appreciated!

Comment: empty array will be returned if the query returns no result.

Comment: yes, I realize that. But is the reverse true? Should `response.body` contain the json objects if the query returns objects. At this point I believe the query should contain objects.

Comment: Thats true. If the reponse returns objects then the response will have them, of course serialized to json.

Comment: OK, thanks for the sense check. Thought I was going crazy there. The problem must be in the way the spec is set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Both your controller and spec are somewhat off.

> You don't need to call `to_json` on the object that you want to render.
>   If you use the `:json` option, render will automatically call `to_json`
>   for you.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

The reason your spec is giving you `"[]"` is that `Model.where(some_conditions)` is returning an empty collection. An empty collection renders as an empty array in JSON.

Either the scope does not work as intended or your test setup is flawed. Remember that let variables are lazy loading and you either need to use `let!` or reference the variable for records to be inserted into the test db.

```
# polyfill for Rails 4. Remove if you are using Rails 5.
let(:parsed_response) { response.body.to_json }

describe "GET #index" do  
  # or use fixtures / factories
  let!(:model) { Model.create!(foo: 'bar') }
  before :each do
    get :index, filtered: 'someValue'
  end
  expect(parsed_response.first["id"].to_i).to eq model.id
end
```

Comment: Additionally controller specs are on their way with the arrival of Rails 5 and the depreciation of many of the methods like `assigns` and `assert_renders`. Use [request specs instead](https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html) for future proof specs.